# Drawing shapes on an image control and save the new image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, drawing

This is a wpf project in which i have a window that views some images in image controls - each image is viewed alone in the window - and i want to add the ability to draw some shapes or write a text on the image and then save the edited image.

I tried putting the image control inside an inkcanvas but that didn't really gave me what i want.

so how can i achieve that ?

Comment: So you have seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5199903/1136211)?

Comment: the inkcanvas lets you free draw, i want shapes not free drawing.

Comment: RenderTargetBitmap is still the right way. Put your image and whatever else in a common container, e.g. a Canvas, and then draw that to a RenderTargetBitmap.